# How do you use OAuth2 authentication for use with DevOps REST services API - service to service?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to do a service to service ADO REST call, from my application to ADO, on behalf of the application, not the user logged in to it.

Microsoft provide REST APIs to do things like create a release pipeline. See here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#security

The documentation is really confusing here, as it refers to the Oauth 2 flow as being "accessCode" which as far as I can see, isn't the name of any valid type of flow.

In the main docs for calling APIs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops

it says that the request body should be like this:

```
client_assertion_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer&client_assertion={0}&grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer&assertion={1}&redirect_uri={2}
```

where

{0}: URL encoded client secret acquired when the app was registered

{1}: URL encoded "code" provided via the code query parameter to your callback URL

{2}: callback URL registered with the app

This is at odds with the documentation for creating a release (first link) which says:

Type: oauth2
Flow: accessCode

Authorization URL: https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/oauth2/authorize&response_type=Assertion

Token URL: https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/oauth2/token?client_assertion_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer&grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer

So **firstly**, does anyone know which documentation is right, the first or the second ?

And **secondly**, how do I make a service to service to call from my application, to call these API's on behalf of the the application, rather than the user ?

I don't want the users of the application to have permissions to create a release within the app as many will not even be ADO users, let alone have permissions to create releases.

I would have thought that the API would support an Oauth 2 grant type of client_credentials (authorization code grant) but I can't see any examples of this in the documentation for ADO REST services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To authenticate your web app users for REST API access, you should follow documentation below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops

First, register your web app and get an app ID from Azure DevOps Services. Using that app ID, send your users to Azure DevOps Services to authorize your app to access their organizations. Next, use that authorization to get an access token for that user. When you call Azure DevOps Services APIs for that user, use that user's access token.

[image: Usually you add a link or button to your site that navigates the user to the Azure DevOps Services authorization endpoint]

Comment: Thanks, but the second half of my question was about service to service authentication. I don't want to use an access token from the user, as the users of the app will not be devops users.

Comment: Specifically, this issue:

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/6756

Comment: There is no service account in devops, user account is necessary. You can only add user accounts in devops.

Comment: If you do want to have this feature, you may submit a suggestion at website https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21